# Hilchos Shabbos audio shiurim online?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, product-recommendation, internet

I'm looking for audio shiurim on hilchos Shabbos. I'd prefer someone who goes through the halachos thoroughly but is very lema'aseh. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Nissan Kaplan has a good set of [shiurim](http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/hals.php?t1=shabbos)

he also goes through most of chelek 3 in the mishna berura [here](http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/cd.php?cdall=Halacha/Mishna_Berura_Chelek_3-amudY)

Answer (score 1):

You can download R. Yitzchak Berkowitz’s shiurim on Chelek Gimmel of the Mishnah Berurah from [here](http://www.torahdownloads.com/c-262.html)

Answer (score 0):

YUTorah.org has (as of right now) over 3800 audio shiurim on Hilchos Shabbos, [here](http://www.yutorah.org/Halacha/Jewish_Law/Shabbat). I would personally recommend Rabbi Elchanan Adler, Rabbi Jeremy Wieder, and Rabbi Herschel Schachter's shiurim, for clear, interesting, and relevant content.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't listened to much else; but I know that those are good.